# compress tar from ubunut to a windows system via ssh

Tags: ubuntu, windows, openssh, ssh-tunneling

I have a windows system that i want to use for a backup of a local ubuntu server. I want to compress a folder and save it on the windows system. I have installed openssh on the window  system and I can copy files with scp to it.

but when I try to tar a big folder I get the error broken pipe.

```
nice -n 10 tar -c -I 'xz -0 -T0 -v' -f - /var/lib/docker | ssh user@192.168.2.236 "cat > /e:/backup/wk18/dockerAM.tar.xz"
```

I have tested with this and this works for just copy.

```
scp /var/lib/docker/test user@192.168.2.236:/e:/backup/wk18/
```

Im thinking I might just have a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: When does this error occur, immediately or after some time? I piped a small amount of data into ssh/cat (`cat filename.local |ssh user4@192.168.x.y "cat > filename.remote"`), but in a linux-linux environment, without a broken pipe error.

Comment: its more than one file that I am trying to copy.